# Is it correct that we use "be" instead of "do" after "would"?

Tags: modal-verbs, syntax

for example in the following sentence she can not do any useful thing.

> She wouldn’t be any help, would she?

Is it true that we can not use "do" after "would"?

Answer (score 1):

The sentence should be:

> She wouldn’t be *of* any help, would she?

You *can* use do:

> She wouldn’t do anything helpful, would she?

Comment: thanks. what about "let it be.". can we say "let it do."?

Comment: You say "let's do it" which means "let us do it." So, you need to say who intends to do it. You can't say "let it do" - because it's not clear who is doing it. "Be" means "is" (in present continuous) or "was" (in past tense) and just indicates the state of "being" and not doing anything. "Do" refers to actively doing something.